# Does $setIntersection work with objects?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I cant seem to get $setIntersection to work with objects.

Example:

Object 1:

```
[
  {name: "test5", value:5},
  {name: "test4", value:4},
  {name: "test3", value:3},
  {name: "test2", value:2}
]
```

Object 2:

```
[
  {name: "test5", value:5},
  {name: "test422", value:422},
  {name: "test333", value:3333},
  {name: "test211", value:211}
]
```

$setIntersection would return me [] instead of this:

```
[
  {name: "test5', value:5}
]
```

If $setIntersection does not work with Objects, is there any work around that I can use?

Comment: What code are you actually running? Because if I do it ( with correct structures) then correct result is exactly what I get. It would help your question if you stated exactly what you are doing and you also realized that `=` has no place in JavaScript Object assignment. You mean `value: 5`

Comment: Oh yes. I meant : instead of =. 
I am running mongodb with node.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you are doing it wrong:

If I insert an object with an array like so:

```
db.test.insert({
    "a" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "test5",
            "value" : 5.0
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "test4",
            "value" : 4.0
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "test3",
            "value" : 3.0
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "test2",
            "value" : 2.0
        }
    ]
})
```

And I run an `.aggregate()` with [`$setInsersection`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIntersection/) and the supplied array of objects like so:

```
db.getCollection('test').aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "a": {
      "$setIntersection": [
        "$a",
        [
          {name: "test5", value: 5},
          {name: "test422", value: 422},
          {name: "test333", value: 3333},
          {name: "test211", value: 211}
        ]
      ]    
    }  
  }}
])
```

Then I get the expected result:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59f02df75b9b8bb266a563cb"),
    "a" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "test5",
            "value" : 5.0
        }
    ]
}
```

If the properties are "reversed", as in:

```
db.getCollection('test').aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "a": {
      "$setIntersection": [
        "$a",
        [
          { value: 5, name: "test5" },
          {name: "test422", value: 422},
          {name: "test333", value: 3333},
          {name: "test211", value: 211}
        ]
      ]    
    }  
  }}
])
```

Then the result array is "empty", as should be expected because `{ "name": "test5", "value": 5 }` is not the same as `{ "value": 5, "test": name }` as far as a "set" is concerned.

Comment: Does this work when both arrays are actually fields of the same document? Cause I using it like this `$setIntersection: ["$field1", "$field2"]`. The format of field 1 and field 2 are the same as the example I used.

Comment: @CodingNoobie A "field" is a "field", and an "array" is an "array". Two different things. You can do `$setIntersection: [ ["$field1"], ["$field2"] ]` wrapping the "singular" values in an array, but there would be little point when you can do `$eq: [ "$field1", "$field2" ]` instead. It seems like you are asking the wrong question. Perhaps you should [Ask a new Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) instead, and be clear about what you are asking when you do. This answers "array comparison", which is what `$setIntersection` does.

Comment: Oh the fields are actually arrays. Example: `fieldName: [<arrayHere>]`

Comment: @CodingNoobie So that is exactly what is being answered. Try the example, see the result and understand what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot compare the arrays in two different documents here. For this to work, both of these arrays need to be in same document (or supplied directly as argument instead of the field name).

`$setIntersection` takes two or more arrays as input. It does not compare objects in different documents, which I think is what you are doing.

The following commands worked fine for me:
**Insert:**

```
db.mycol.insert({f1:[
  {name: "test5", value:5},
  {name: "test4", value:4},
  {name: "test3", value:3},
  {name: "test2", value:2}
],f2:[
  {name: "test5", value:5},
  {name: "test422", value:422},
  {name: "test333", value:3333},
  {name: "test211", value:211}
]})
```

**Output:**
`WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })`

**Aggregate:**

```
db.mycol.aggregate([{$project:{com:{$setIntersection:["$f1","$f2"]}}}])
```

**Output:**

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59f02eba7f11fa2e1df15e53"), "com" : [ { "name" : "test5", "value" : 5 } ] }
```

Comment: There is no such need to "be in the same document". ANY construction of BSON is perfectly valid. You can ( though not practical ) submit "both" arrays as arguments to the operator. It's generally more practical for "at least one" to be present in the document itself. But not a "requirement" at all.

Comment: My point was you cannot compare the arrays in different docs. Yes, supplying the whole array as argument will work, and technically it wont be "in a same document."

Comment: The only "point" I see is intrinsically incorrect. So I am informing you of what you are stating "incorrectly". Nobody said anything about "different documents", and you've basically "made that up" yourself. Nothing to do with the question asked.

Comment: I did say "which I think is what you are doing". You are right, he did not mention different docs. If he is using it correctly like both you and I have posted, there is no reason to get `[]` as output.