# How to get multiple distinct fields in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, distinct

I am using MongoDB with Nodejs.
For example:

```
Array = [{name: 'Sam',  age: 26, hobby: 'Baseball'},
         {name: 'Sam',  age: 30, hobby: 'Baseball'},
         {name: 'John', age: 26, hobby: 'Baseball'},
         {name: 'Mike', age: 32, hobby: 'Baseball'},
         {name: 'Max',  age: 32, hobby: 'Baseball'},]
```

I want a query which doesnt repeat any value of `name` and `age` and gives me result =>
`[ {name: 'Sam', age: 26, hobby: 'Baseball'},{name: 'Mike', age: 32, hobby: 'Baseball'} ]`

Is it possible to using MongoDB and Nodejs?

I checked distinct() but it only takes one filled as a query.

Comment: what happned to John and Max?

Comment: @varman In them `age` is repeating.  I want records in which no same value is repeated of field `name` and `age`

Comment: did you tried *$unwind* pipeline? Please go through [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/) page

Comment: @Bubai Actually i am new to this so its hard to understand this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$facet` to categories name and age

- `$sort` to sort by age
- `$facet` to categorie incoming data into two groups. One is group by name and other one is group by age.
- `$setIntersection` to get the common objects of two arrays. But please have a look on [if the key order is changed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46925471/7975771)

The script is

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $sort: { age: 1 } },
  {
    $facet: {
      nameGroup: [
        {
          $group: {
            _id: "$name",
            name: { $first: "$name" },
            age: { $first: "$age" },
            hobby: { $first: "$hobby" }
          }
        },
        { $project: { _id: 0 } }
      ],
      ageGroup: [
        {
          $group: {
            _id: "$age",
            name: { $first: "$name" },
            age: { $first: "$age" },
            hobby: { $first: "$hobby" }
          }
        },
        { $project: { _id: 0 } }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      data: { "$setIntersection": [ "$nameGroup", "$ageGroup" ] }
    }
  }
])
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/HqJNc-H2t1M)**

Comment: thank you very very much brother. I searched it many times but didnt found anything. You solved it. This was my first question on StackOverFlow and i am glad i got the solution so fast.